# Don't know why the css isn't linking?

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

So I'm about to start to code a website using Sublime Text, but I have not touched code in a couple of months (5-7) so I am trying to get used to it again. So I have created my HTML and CSS page, but even though the CSS link is right, it is not displaying in browser. I know once you tell me I will be kicking myself but why is it not showing up?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="home.css">
<title>Home</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>GymHub</h1>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: are you receiving any errors in your console?

Comment: Is it in the same folder as the html?Are there any css rules in there?Edit your question with its content

Comment: Is the file home.css in the same directory as the html? or is it in another folder?

Comment: where is the css file? it needs to be in the root of the website folder

Comment: add **/** to the end of your code like this `<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='css/style.css'/>` and make sure that you clean your browser and of your css file path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code assumes that your folder structure is like this (where your css file is a sibling to the html):

```
 index.html

 home.css
```

However, make sure that if your project setup is in a way that your css is in a folder, you should reflect that in the code:

```
 index.html

 -- css

    home.css
```

And you would then put this in your html file:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/home.css">
```

Comment: No problem, please accept (tick) as it's helped :) @matty

Answer (score 0):

you have to create a root-directory with the exact adress of the css file , but maybe its because you forgot to make a backslash at the end of the link ( i am not sure )

Answer (score -1):

You are missing the slash in link tag. Try this. Also make sure css file is in same directory.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="home.css"/>  
<title>Home</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>GymHub</h1>


</body>
</html>
```